# Changing Background in Mate/Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mate, desktop-background

I just updated to Mate 22.04 - successfully: Now I would like to change the initial background (I do not like the jellyfish) and would like to return to Mate 20.04's background. I thought I can do that via the Control Centre and then pick an image in /usr/share/background.... But it does not work this way. Can anybody help?
B.[image]

Comment: what if you click the right mouse on the desktop?

Comment: Thos only changes the background on the 'normal' background but not the initial one when staring the computer

Comment: [this](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-change-login-screen-background-in-ubuntu-mate-21-04/24384)?

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

using the dconf editor, change the setting in
org.gnome.desktop.background to 'scaled'
Be careful, you can do a lot of damage if you set things wrong in dconf
Bob

Comment: Needs more details.